# nvd3 "line plus bar chart" example not showing

Tags: javascript, python, graph, nvd3.js

I found nvd3 for creating graphs and I like [Line plus bar chart](http://nvd3.org/ghpages/linePlusBar.html). But I can't even make their example work. Where am I doing mistake? I have tried including almost all js scripts there is on example page(above link). This is my python code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
{% load staticfiles %}
    <style>
        #chart svg {
            height: 400px;
        }
    </style>

<link href="{% static "css/nv.d3.css" %}" rel="stylesheet">

<script src="{% static "js/d3.v3/d3.v3.min.js" %}"></script>
<script src="{% static "js/d3.v3/d3.v3.js" %}"></script>
<script src="{% static "js/d3.v3/fisheye.js" %}"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{% static "js/graph/linePlusBar.js" %}"></script>
</head>

<body>
<div id="chart">
    <svg> </svg>
</div>

<h1>{{ stock.name }} dividend history</h1>
<ul>
{% for dividend in stock.dividend_set.all %}
    <li>{{ dividend.date}} - {{dividend.amount}}</li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>
</body>
</html>
```

and this is html output for loaded page

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">

    <style>
        #chart svg {
            height: 400px;
        }
    </style>

<link href="/static/css/nv.d3.css" rel="stylesheet">

<script src="/static/js/d3.v3/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
<script src="/static/js/d3.v3/d3.v3.js"></script>
<script src="/static/js/d3.v3/fisheye.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/static/js/graph/linePlusBar.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<div id="chart">
    <svg> </svg>
</div>

<h1>Agilent Technolog dividend history</h1>
<ul>

    <li>Nov. 1, 2006 - 2.057</li>

    <li>March 30, 2012 - 0.1</li>

    <li>June 29, 2012 - 0.1</li>

    <li>Sept. 28, 2012 - 0.1</li>

    <li>Dec. 27, 2012 - 0.1</li>

    <li>March 28, 2013 - 0.12</li>

</ul>
</body>
</html>
```

And default linePlusBar.js

```
nv.addGraph(function() {
    var testdata = exampleData(),
        chart = nv.models.linePlusBarChart()
            .margin({top: 30, right: 60, bottom: 50, left: 70})
            .x(function(d,i) { return i })
            .color(d3.scale.category10().range());

    chart.xAxis.tickFormat(function(d) {
        var dx = testdata[0].values[d] && testdata[0].values[d].x || 0;
        return d3.time.format('%x')(new Date(dx))
    });

    chart.y1Axis
        .tickFormat(d3.format(',f'));

    chart.y2Axis
        .tickFormat(function(d) { return '$' + d3.format(',f')(d) });

    chart.bars.forceY([0]);
    //chart.lines.forceY([0]);

    d3.select('#chart svg')
        .datum(exampleData())
        .transition().duration(500).call(chart);

    nv.utils.windowResize(chart.update);

    return chart;
});



function exampleData() {
    return [
        {
            "key" : "Quantity" ,
            "bar": true,
            "values" : [ [ 1136005200000 , 1271000.0] , [ 1138683600000 , 1271000.0] , [ 1141102800000 , 1271000.0] , [ 1143781200000 , 0] , [ 1146369600000 , 0] , [ 1149048000000 , 0] , [ 1151640000000 , 0] , [ 1154318400000 , 0] , [ 1156996800000 , 0] , [ 1159588800000 , 3899486.0] , [ 1162270800000 , 3899486.0] , [ 1164862800000 , 3899486.0] , [ 1167541200000 , 3564700.0] , [ 1170219600000 , 3564700.0] , [ 1172638800000 , 3564700.0] , [ 1175313600000 , 2648493.0] , [ 1177905600000 , 2648493.0] , [ 1180584000000 , 2648493.0] , [ 1183176000000 , 2522993.0] , [ 1185854400000 , 2522993.0] , [ 1188532800000 , 2522993.0] , [ 1191124800000 , 2906501.0] , [ 1193803200000 , 2906501.0] , [ 1196398800000 , 2906501.0] , [ 1199077200000 , 2206761.0] , [ 1201755600000 , 2206761.0] , [ 1204261200000 , 2206761.0] , [ 1206936000000 , 2287726.0] , [ 1209528000000 , 2287726.0] , [ 1212206400000 , 2287726.0] , [ 1214798400000 , 2732646.0] , [ 1217476800000 , 2732646.0] , [ 1220155200000 , 2732646.0] , [ 1222747200000 , 2599196.0] , [ 1225425600000 , 2599196.0] , [ 1228021200000 , 2599196.0] , [ 1230699600000 , 1924387.0] , [ 1233378000000 , 1924387.0] , [ 1235797200000 , 1924387.0] , [ 1238472000000 , 1756311.0] , [ 1241064000000 , 1756311.0] , [ 1243742400000 , 1756311.0] , [ 1246334400000 , 1743470.0] , [ 1249012800000 , 1743470.0] , [ 1251691200000 , 1743470.0] , [ 1254283200000 , 1519010.0] , [ 1256961600000 , 1519010.0] , [ 1259557200000 , 1519010.0] , [ 1262235600000 , 1591444.0] , [ 1264914000000 , 1591444.0] , [ 1267333200000 , 1591444.0] , [ 1270008000000 , 1543784.0] , [ 1272600000000 , 1543784.0] , [ 1275278400000 , 1543784.0] , [ 1277870400000 , 1309915.0] , [ 1280548800000 , 1309915.0] , [ 1283227200000 , 1309915.0] , [ 1285819200000 , 1331875.0] , [ 1288497600000 , 1331875.0] , [ 1291093200000 , 1331875.0] , [ 1293771600000 , 1331875.0] , [ 1296450000000 , 1154695.0] , [ 1298869200000 , 1154695.0] , [ 1301544000000 , 1194025.0] , [ 1304136000000 , 1194025.0] , [ 1306814400000 , 1194025.0] , [ 1309406400000 , 1194025.0] , [ 1312084800000 , 1194025.0] , [ 1314763200000 , 1244525.0] , [ 1317355200000 , 475000.0] , [ 1320033600000 , 475000.0] , [ 1322629200000 , 475000.0] , [ 1325307600000 , 690033.0] , [ 1327986000000 , 690033.0] , [ 1330491600000 , 690033.0] , [ 1333166400000 , 514733.0] , [ 1335758400000 , 514733.0]]
        } ,

        {
            "key" : "Price" ,
            "values" : [ [ 1136005200000 , 71.89] , [ 1138683600000 , 75.51] , [ 1141102800000 , 68.49] , [ 1143781200000 , 62.72] , [ 1146369600000 , 70.39] , [ 1149048000000 , 59.77] , [ 1151640000000 , 57.27] , [ 1154318400000 , 67.96] , [ 1156996800000 , 67.85] , [ 1159588800000 , 76.98] , [ 1162270800000 , 81.08] , [ 1164862800000 , 91.66] , [ 1167541200000 , 84.84] , [ 1170219600000 , 85.73] , [ 1172638800000 , 84.61] , [ 1175313600000 , 92.91] , [ 1177905600000 , 99.8] , [ 1180584000000 , 121.191] , [ 1183176000000 , 122.04] , [ 1185854400000 , 131.76] , [ 1188532800000 , 138.48] , [ 1191124800000 , 153.47] , [ 1193803200000 , 189.95] , [ 1196398800000 , 182.22] , [ 1199077200000 , 198.08] , [ 1201755600000 , 135.36] , [ 1204261200000 , 125.02] , [ 1206936000000 , 143.5] , [ 1209528000000 , 173.95] , [ 1212206400000 , 188.75] , [ 1214798400000 , 167.44] , [ 1217476800000 , 158.95] , [ 1220155200000 , 169.53] , [ 1222747200000 , 113.66] , [ 1225425600000 , 107.59] , [ 1228021200000 , 92.67] , [ 1230699600000 , 85.35] , [ 1233378000000 , 90.13] , [ 1235797200000 , 89.31] , [ 1238472000000 , 105.12] , [ 1241064000000 , 125.83] , [ 1243742400000 , 135.81] , [ 1246334400000 , 142.43] , [ 1249012800000 , 163.39] , [ 1251691200000 , 168.21] , [ 1254283200000 , 185.35] , [ 1256961600000 , 188.5] , [ 1259557200000 , 199.91] , [ 1262235600000 , 210.732] , [ 1264914000000 , 192.063] , [ 1267333200000 , 204.62] , [ 1270008000000 , 235.0] , [ 1272600000000 , 261.09] , [ 1275278400000 , 256.88] , [ 1277870400000 , 251.53] , [ 1280548800000 , 257.25] , [ 1283227200000 , 243.1] , [ 1285819200000 , 283.75] , [ 1288497600000 , 300.98] , [ 1291093200000 , 311.15] , [ 1293771600000 , 322.56] , [ 1296450000000 , 339.32] , [ 1298869200000 , 353.21] , [ 1301544000000 , 348.5075] , [ 1304136000000 , 350.13] , [ 1306814400000 , 347.83] , [ 1309406400000 , 335.67] , [ 1312084800000 , 390.48] , [ 1314763200000 , 384.83] , [ 1317355200000 , 381.32] , [ 1320033600000 , 404.78] , [ 1322629200000 , 382.2] , [ 1325307600000 , 405.0] , [ 1327986000000 , 456.48] , [ 1330491600000 , 542.44] , [ 1333166400000 , 599.55] , [ 1335758400000 , 583.98]]
        }
    ].map(function(series) {
            series.values = series.values.map(function(d) { return {x: d[0], y: d[1] } });
            return series;
        });
}
```

What am I missing? svg is blank on my html page. Thanks for any help, I am really lost on this trivial thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you have not added the NVD3 library to your project. You can get it from [here](http://cdnjs.com/libraries/nvd3).

Tested your code with the nvd3 javascript library on my machine and it works fine. Looks like this for me.
[image]

Answer (score 4):

If you are using Python and NVD3, you might want to look at python-nvd3 :
https://github.com/areski/python-nvd3

We are also working on django wrapper:
https://github.com/areski/django-nvd3